# V4L2: Get device/input status

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver, v4l2

Maybe anybody will know the answer to the next question...

I have plugged in usb digital camera (it has one input pin - 0).

I check input status every 5 seconds via structure: [v4l2_input](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/kernel/generated/media/re31.html#v4l2-input) (here is the example: http://pastebin.com/FFvNAkQ3), to process situation if one of the flags is set (V4L2_IN_ST_NO_POWER or V4L2_IN_ST_NO_SIGNAL or V4L2_IN_ST_NO_H_LOCK).

The problem is that even i unplug my usb digital camera, the input status is always 0 (0x00). Why the driver does not change input status flag when the device is unplugged?

Maybe it is possible to check device status not only input pin? If yes, then which ioctl request should be set...?

Comment: Are you checking the return value of the ioctl call? If the device is unplugged, you might find that it is no longer a valid input call and thus you would get a return error.

Comment: Also, note the disclaimer on the status field. It says that the field is only valid if you have it selected as the current input. Is that the case?